# Bloquear un usuario si ya hay otro usuario dentro

Tags: php

Tengo una web, que ya está terminada, pero en una de las secciones necesito  limitar la entrada a solo un usuario, es decir, que cuando haya un usuario dentro de esa sección  no pueda entrar ningún otro hasta que el primero que entró haya salido.

Según he visto, esto se puede hacer con **semáforos**, pero no encuentro una manera clara de solucionar mi problema.

Dejo por aquí un fragmento del código.

```
<td class="ColIzq">
    <?if($permisos->escritura && $ult_est['id']!='1' && $ult_est['id']!='5'){?>     
        <?
            $ListOpe = new ListaOperadores();
            $id_op_csme = $ListOpe->operador_csme($_SESSION['usuario_login']);
            $semaphore_max = 1;
            $semaphore_perm = 0666;
            $semaphore_autorelease = 1;
            $nowait = true;

            $sem_id = sem_get($id_op_csme, $semaphore_max, $semaphore_perm, $semaphore_autorelease);
        ?>

        <?if(sem_acquire($sem_id, $nowait)){?>
            <a href="<?echo $appDir."/Llamadas/_wf_incidencia.php"?>?<?php echo 'id_sede='.$Sede->get_Id().'&id_inc='.$var->Incidencia->get_Id(); ?>" ><input type="button" value="&nbsp;<?_translate("Nueva actuaci&oacute;n")?>&nbsp;" /></a>
        <?}else{?>
            <a href="<?echo $appDir."/Llamadas/_wf_incidencia.php"?>?<?php echo 'id_sede='.$Sede->get_Id().'&id_inc='.$var->Incidencia->get_Id(); ?>" ><input type="button" onclick="simperform()" value="&nbsp;<?_translate("Nueva actuaci&oacute;n")?>&nbsp;" /></a>
        <?}?>
```

La idea es que cuando alguien esté dentro de ese botón llamado **Nueva actuacion** no pueda entrar nadie más.

Comment: Esto sería muy fácil con una base de datos. Una tabla `usuario` y otra tabla `logged` con una sola fila y una columna booleana. Cuando el primer usuario entra esa variable se pone en `TRUE`. El formulario de login lee el valor de esa columna (digamos cada segundo) y no se activa si no es `FALSE`. Desde la sesión controlas cuando el usuario salga para cambiar el valor de la variable.

Comment: El problema que veo en esa solución es que no se trata de un login, una vez el usuario esté en esa página ya debe de estar conectado y su sesión activa, el botón que muestro en el código es una redirección a otra página y si dos o más usuarios entran en la pa siguiente página habrá bastantes errores.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu comentario. En la página monousuario puedes poner un control de entrada/salida, de modo que cuando alguien entre en ella se encienda el indicador (en la base de datos o en otro sitio) y cuando salga se apague para que otro pueda entrar... Yo creo que nada mejor que la base de datos, porque es información persistente, que se puede leer desde cualquier sitio sin necesidad de entrar a la página.

Comment: ¿podrías ponerme algún enlace donde muestre esto que me estás diciendo? y por cierto, muchas gracias por tu tiempo!.

Comment: No puedo ponerte un enlace a mi mente  :)  Lo que te digo es una forma en la que resolvería el asunto. Lo más delicado aquí es esto: la forma de controlar cuando alguien entra y sale en esa página. Habrá varias formas de hacerlo. La más simple, creo, sería invocando un script que lea en la base de datos el estado de la columna booleana (que sería la luz del semáforo). Si está en `TRUE` hay alguien dentro y la otra persona no podrá acceder, si está en `FALSE` no hay nadie dentro, la otra persona podrá entrar y la columna booleana se pondrá de inmediato en `TRUE` hasta que salga...